# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object occurs when i try to run my php

Tags: php, database

I have made a database with two tables name 'user'&'volley'. This php code helps me to connect those tables and retrieve the data.

i get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in /home/u115908902/public_html/Wishes.php on line 11

while i try to run my php code .

```
<?php 
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("mysql.hostinger.in","willi","123","pract"); 

global $mysqli;
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT user.name AS userName,
volley.wishes AS userWishes
FROM user,volley 
WHERE user.name = 'mick' AND volley.id=user.id");

$resultSet = array();
while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
array_push($resultSet,
array(
$users = $rows['userName'],
$volleys = $rows['userWishes']));
echo json_encode(array("resultSet"=>$resultSet));
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: 1.`$mysqli =new mysqli(` 2.`global $mysqli;` not needed.3. `$resultSet = array();` first you did query with same variable name (`$resultSet = $mysqli->query(`) and after that you over-write it with empty array then how you will get anything. change the name

Comment: william check  answers below and if worked then mark+up-vote one as accepted answer. you can up-vote others too if they are useful too. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are destroying your result set with the line `$resultSet = array();`

Also you are making the unload of the resultset overly complex it does not need to be

```
<?php 
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi("mysql.hostinger.in","willi","123","pract"); 

// remove this line its nonsence    
//global $mysqli;

$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT user.name AS userName,
                                    volley.wishes AS userWishes
                             FROM user,volley 
                             WHERE user.name = 'mick' AND volley.id=user.id");

// remove this line it destroys your resultset    
//$resultSet = array();

$results = array();

while($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc()){
    $results[] = $row;
}

// this does not belong in the loop
mysqli_close($mysqli);
// nor does this
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: I edited your answer, as you used the wrong variable for mysqli_close(). Maybe that's why whoever downvoted you, downvoted you. If that's the case, it's pretty lame if you ask me.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  still one error is there in the very last  code statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks Ralph. Think I am suffering a payback from something from way back. Now all my comment have been remove for some reason.